# randomly insert elements in arrays using jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have an array of 10 elements (sequence is important)

and I want to insert four elements at random spots, without messing up the order of the existing array

what is the best way?

Thanks and Merry Christmas

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Look at [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: I don;t fully understand.  If I have a list like [A,B,C] and i randomly inserted `D`, then wouldn't the resulting [A,D,B,C] mess up the order of the existing array?

Comment: Not too random if you don't want to mess with the existing order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `splice()`

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var b = [20, 21, 22, 23];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
    a.splice(idx, 0, b[i]);
}

console.log(a)
// returns something like [23, 1, 2, 3, 22, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 8, 21, 9, 10]
```

Reference **[MDN Array.prototype.splice() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

If this is not the expected output please provide a sample

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    var randomSpot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);    
    myArray[randomSpot] = i;
}
```